# CSS issue with responsive image resizing to 100% height when hiding footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am far from a CSS wizard and need some help/suggestions on how to do the following.

I am using Bootstrap to do a responsive layout and need a 2 row layout. 3 columns in the first row and one column in the second row.

The top 3rd column will have an image and the second row is a horizontal scrolling image carousel.

The second row (carousel) will hide on a window event. When that occurs we would like the image to resize and fill the screen 100% in height.

The other criteria is height will always be 100% and there should never be overflow or scrollbars.

I have done a lot of searching for examples or similar issues and have mainly found how to fill to 100% height with a nav/header + lower content div, but have not seen this scenario.

I actually have this working, but I think it is a little clunky (see the JSFiddle).

So question, is there a way to do what I've done, but have the image height resize with purely CSS instead of via JavaScript as I've done in the demo, where we modify the element style?  Appreciate the time.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A9E87/)

```
<div class='container'>
  <div id='row1'>
    <div>content 1</div>
    <div>content 2</div>
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Lion_waiting_in_Namibia.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div id='row2'>Hide this with JS and image should get big</div>
</div>
<div style='background-color:red; position:absolute; bottom:0;'>
  <input type='button'>
</div>

body{
    height:250px;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    background-color:blue;
}
#row1 {
    height:95%;
    max-height:100%;
}
#row1 div {
    float:left;
}
#row1.max {
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
#row1 img {
    height:inherit;
    max-height:inherit;
}
#row2 {
    height:auto;
    background-color:yellow;
}
.hide {
    position:absolute;
    top:-9999px;
    left:-9999px;
}

$('input').on('click', function () {
    var r1 = $("#row1");
    var r2 = $("#row2");
    if (r2.hasClass("hide")) 
    {
        r2.removeClass("hide");
        r1.removeClass("max");
    }
    else 
    {
        r2.addClass("hide");
        r1.addClass("max");
    }

    $("input").attr('value', $("#row1").height());
});
```

Comment: you are setting the body height to 250 max, why? According to that setting, it actually works. Think about it from the Container perspective, deal with container as the one that has fixed height, when button clicked it gets 100% height.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do but I think what you are looking for is height: auto; on the image.

Comment: Besides, you are doing it purely css, the only JS you are using is for click events, which is the right way to go.

Comment: Forgot to add that you might need to put max-height: 100% as well. But still not sure what you are trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `toggleClass`, so you JS looks like this:

```
$('input').on('click', function () {   
    $('#row1').toggleClass('max');
    $('#row2').toggleClass('hide');

    $('input').attr('value', $('#row1').height());
});
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A9E87/8/)